# Comment and reply, joining 3 tables query

Tags: php, sql

I have been searching now for a while, but still did not find an optimal solution. I have three tables: posts, membership and comments. I want to have a Comment and reply system.

These are my tables:

**Main posts:**

```
post_id | image_url | image_thumb_url | title | text | date | sender_id
```

**Membership:**

```
user_id | username | pw | email |
```

**Comments (replies) to posts:**

```
com_id | comment | post_id_fk | user_id_fk | ip | date
```

I currently have a query for retrieving the posts with the membership data:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `membership` ON `posts`.`sender_id` = `membership`.`user_id`
UNION SELECT * FROM `posts`
      RIGHT JOIN `membership` ON `posts`.`sender_id` = `membership`.`user_id`
      ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT $limit $start;
```

I now want to add the replies to  each posts, containing the membership data. Does anyone have suggestion or perhaps a better solution ?

Comment: Why are you using a `LEFT JOIN`? Can a post be submitted by someone who isn't a member?

Comment: Do you want the `LIMIT` to apply to the number of posts, or posts+comments?

Comment: And what is the union for? You want to list members with no posts as well?

Comment: @Barmar, exactly I wanted to have people submit messages, who are not members

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS P
LEFT JOIN comments AS C
ON P.post_id = C.post_id_fk
LEFT JOIN membership AS POST_MEMBER
ON POST_MEMBER.user_id = P.sender_id
LEFT JOIN membership AS REPLY_MEMBER
ON REPLY_MEMBER.user_id = C.user_id_fk
```